# change format in date (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, object

I have a very simple query which i am not getting how to correct this format structure.

I have a string as follows

```
var date = "11/21/2016'
```

I need to change it to this format

```
var date = '20161122'
```

Any idea how to achieve this

Comment: Do you want to do this in pure JS or using library is fine?

Comment: pure js would be fine... any suggestions ?

Comment: Will it always follow that (01/01/2016) or can it be like 1/1/16?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You should use a date library like Moment.js or Date.js. if you cant then you can do something like this `var dt = new Date(date); '' + dt.getFullYear() + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + dt.getDate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest [moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js):

```
moment('11/21/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a library:

```
var parts = date.split("/");
var finalDate = parts[2] + parts[0] + parts[1];
```

The `finalDate` is the answer.